How do you obtain the coordinates of 3D space from the FLRW metric?
Under the assumptions of homogeneity and isotropy, it can be deduced that for a one-parameter family of spacelike surfaces folliating spacetime, the curvature within each such surface is constant. This gives the FLRW metric, defined as:
$$
ds^2 = -d\tau^2 + a^2(\tau) \begin{cases} 
d\psi^2 + \sin^2\psi (d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d\phi^2) \\ 
dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 \\
d\psi^2 + \sinh^2 \psi (d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d\phi^2) \end{cases}
$$
These are the three cases of constant spatial curvature, with the above one corresponding to the spatial metric of a 3-sphere embedded in 4D-space, the middle one being ordinary flat space, and the bottom one being a hyperbolic surface embedded in 4D-space. In one of the assignments in Wald's General Relativity, it is asked to show that the metric can be written on the form:
$$
ds^2 = -d\tau^2 + a^2(\tau)\left( \frac{dr^2}{1 - kr^2} + r^2 (d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d\phi^2)\right)
$$
where $k = 1$ corresponds to the 3-sphere case, $k = 0$ to the flat case and $k = -1$ to the hyperbolic case. This can be easily seen by the change of variables $\psi \mapsto r = \sin \psi$ for the spherical case and  $\psi \mapsto r = \sinh \psi$ for the hyperbolic case, using the regular tensor transformation laws. For the flat case, the flat spatial metric $dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$ can simply be written in spherical coordinates. Thus, we have obtained a new set of coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$, where the metric takes the new form, as asked in the question.
The problem arises when I try to conceptualize using the coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$ to map different spatial points in spacetime. For the flat case, there is no intuitive issue, but for the other geometries, I'm struggling with this.
For simplicity, let's just focus on the 3-sphere case. A 3-sphere in 4D-space is given by the equation:
$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 = R^2
$$
where $R$ is some constant. An embedding of 3D space into 4D space is an intuitively difficult concept, but I understand that one of these dimensions are there, informally speaking, to "close up" the 3D space. In order to visualize this more clearly, I imagine a 2-sphere embedded in 3D-space. For a 2-dimensional world, where we are restricted to the surface of this sphere, the 3D-coordinates $(x,y,z)$ would (in a sense) not be that meaningful. So for this reason, I'm guessing that $(x,y,z,w)$ is not meaningful either. In an attempt to construct a coordinate system on the surface of this sphere, spherical coordinates do make more sense, since we can now disregard the $r$-coordinate. However, the angles are still kind of hard to give meaning, if we restrict ourself to only understand the world on the 2-sphere - after all, they are angles formed in the outer 3D space.
What I struggle to construct is a set of coordinates on this 2-sphere which can be easily translated into physically interpretable coordinates in the 2D-world. Equivalently, for the 3-sphere, I would want to find a set of coordinates which are easily interpretable in our 3D-world. For example, how would I convert the angles $(\psi, \theta, \phi)$ or the coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$ into cartesian coordinates? Or how would I convert them into spherical spatial coordinates? To me, all of these coordinates are highly abstract, and I don't see how I would attempt to describe a point in spacetime using $(\tau, r, \theta, \phi)$.
Shortly, I just want to know how to interpret $(r, \theta, \phi)$. Even though coordinates are arbitrary on a manifold, I should be able to go from this coordinate system to one that's more interpretable, right? Any help or pointers are appreciated!

Is this just an issue on how to interpret spherical coordinates (i.e. op. 1 in your FLRW metric)?

@controlgroup Yes, exactly! And preferably, in the coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$, i.e. the second equation. However, if the interpretation of the spherical coordinates involves the external 4D (spatial) space, then I'm also wondering how you can "get rid" of the extra dimension when translating it back to 3D space.

If your issue is just interpreting spherical coordinates, note that you don’t actually need to define an additional spatial dimension to properly set stuff up. It is perfectly-fine to call the spatial part of the metric
$$\text{d}\sigma^2=\text{d}r^2+r^2(\text{d}\theta^2+\sin^2(\theta)\text{d}\phi^2)=\text{d}x^2+\text{d}y^2+\text{d}z^2$$
and go from there. In fact, the choice of spatial coordinates is functionally arbitrary; when the manifold is so spatially-symmetric as Minkowski or FLRW, you can foliate it into a family of 1+1-hyperplanes where the metric is just $$\text{d}s^2=c^2\text{d}t^2-\text{d}x^2$$ although it is often desirable to maintain the dimensionality of the manifold.
That is what spherical coordinates are - just a choice of coordinates with a particular flat metric. You specify radius from the origin, latitude, and longitude, and time if you want.

The problem arises when I try to conceptualize using the coordinates (r,θ,ϕ) to map different spatial points in spacetime. For the flat case, there is no intuitive issue, but for the other geometries, I'm struggling with this.

If you have two events in spacetime at different spatial points, and if you know their positions in rectangular coordinates (i.e. $x$, $y$, $z$), then you just have to convert those to spherical coordinates and then use the metric. Spherical-coordinate Minkowski space is flat: its Riemann tensor is zero and so there is no actual curvature.
The coordinate systems you specify aren’t curved; those are just different coordinate systems for the same flat spacetime. One is spherical, one is rectangular, one is hyperbolic, but those are all just different coordinate systems, different ways to assign 3-vectors to each of infinite points in flat space.
In Wald, adding the $k$ stuff in the denominator in the radial component actually does add curvature, leading to  actually-hyperbolic and actually-elliptical geometries. I could very well express those spacetimes in rectangular coordinates, too.
To do whatever math you want to in this FLRW spacetime, just use the regular math. Convert to spherical coordinates first, though.

Thank you for the response! I do understand how the middle case ($k = 0$) is just spherical coordinates, which does not require any additional dimensions to justify. But is it true that the case with $k = 1$ (option 1) is also ordinary spherical coordinates? In other words, if I were to choose any spherical coordinate system around a point $P$ in spacetime, will (for example) the metric component $g_{rr} = a^2(\tau)/(1 - r^2)$, as expressed in those coordinates?

Yes, the coordinates are identical. We're still using $r$, $\theta$, $\phi$ as the spatial coordinates, and events are still referred to as $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$; you're also right about the metric components. Sometimes like in Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates we call the spacetime "coordinates", even though it's just Schwarzschild spacetime with also a special choice of coordinates, but here you're still using regular spherical.

Thank you, this answers my question, since it gives me an interpretation of the coordinates. I do have one last thing that confuses me, in case you can easily spot the misunderstanding (all things following are for the spherical case): The first equation in my question comes from the 3-sphere angles. The second equation, as you're saying, is just the metric in spherical coordinates. How would I reason that the change of variables $\psi \mapsto \sin \psi$ converts these "abstract angles" into regular spherical coordinates? Can I somehow glue this whole thing together?

There, I see a necessary transformation that sends $\sin^2\psi\to r^2$ for a regular $r$ coordinate. The spatial part of the metric in Minkowski is $\text{d}\sigma^2=\text{d}r^2+r^2(\text{d}\theta^2+\sin^2(\theta)\text{d}\phi^2)$; figuring out whichever transformation gets the spatial part there will bring the angles you have right now to regular spherical.

(For reference: FLRW in spherical should be $\text{d}s^2=c^2\text{d}t^2-a^2(t)\big(\text{d}r^2+r^2(\text{d}\theta^2+\sin^2(\theta)\text{d}\phi^2)\big)$, if that helps.)

But the form of the 3-sphere case isn't exactly the spatial part of the Minkowski metric, since it contains the reduced coefficient $1/(1 - r^2)$. Also, to phrase things a bit differently, if I specify unit vectors $dr$, $d\theta$ and $d\phi$ without any context, then that can be taken to mean anything. I could technically set $dx = dr$ in a cartesian coordinate system in the neighbourhood of a point. I understand what the unit vectors $d\psi$, $d\theta$ and $d\phi$ are, but how can I show that the coordinate transformation gives the same $dr$ as in polar coordinates?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
